# I want to generate a random color using rgb in JavaScript but it's not working

Tags: javascript

this is my code

```
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", colorChange)
function colorChange() {
  var arr = []
  for (let i = 0;i<3;i++) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
    arr.push(random)
  }
  document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])"
}
```

first I added an event listener to a button with the class "btn" and then I declared a function and declared an empty array in it called "arr" and then I used a for loop and declared a variable called random to generate three random numbers push
them to the empty array

Answer (score 2):

```
  document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])"
```

Currently, you are passing the static string value `rgb(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])`.

Solution:

```
  document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${arr[0]}, ${arr[1]}, ${arr[2]})`
```

Comment: Simply `rgb(${arr})`

Answer (score 1):

You don't access the array fields. You only wrote a string. Do it this way.

```
 document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + arr[0] + "," + arr[1] + "," + arr[2] +")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Return with your function the rgb string that you need created with random values, like bellow for exemple.

Then just use it where ever you want to use it, like in your `style.backgroundColor` if you wish.

```js
function random_rgb() {
    var o = Math.round, r = Math.random, s = 255;
    return 'rgb(' + o(r()*s) + ',' + o(r()*s) + ',' + o(r()*s) + ')';
}
    
var color = random_rgb();        
document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = color  
console.log(color)
```